# Pokemon Black 2 - Tornadus Event not triggering

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

I am currently trying to catch Tornadus in Black 2.

After forgetting about it until after I defeated the Champion, I returned to Route 7 to trigger the Tornadus event.

Strangely, there was no storm, and there was no event starting grandma outside.
Is there a specific event to trigger the hunt?

Answer (score 4):

Tornadus and Thundurus only show up in Pokemon Black/White respectively, and not in their sequels.

To obtain those Pokemons, you need to either use the Dream Radar app on the 3DS, or trade them from Pokemon Black/White.